# How to decode a hex byte defined as string?

Tags: python, string, hex, byte, decode

I read a printed byte in a file, as a string:

```
a = "b'\xa0-\xfc\xa3\xf8\xd9'"
```

`type(a)` is `str`.

How should I decode it?

The decoded value should be `a02dfca3f8d9`.

A part the file is uploaded here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p12pwwhknu3gr4h/info.log?dl=1

```
[PICA8-P3297] dl-dst output #1 OFPFlowMod(actions=[OFPActionOutput(max_len=65509,port=45)],buffer_id=4294967295,command=0,cookie=16895774056056650001,flags=0,hard_timeout=0,idle_timeout=0,match=OFPMatch(dl_dst=b'\xa0-\xfc\xa3\xf8\xd9',dl_src=b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',dl_type=0,dl_vlan=0,dl_vlan_pcp=0,in_port=0,nw_dst=0,nw_proto=0,nw_src=0,nw_tos=0,tp_dst=0,tp_src=0,wildcards=4194295),out_port=65535,priority=1)
```

I open and get the `dl_dst` value in the file by this line:

```
dl_dst = fm_line.split('OFPMatch')[1].split(',')[0].split('=')[1]
```

`dl_dst` is supposed to be a Mac Address. My question is how to convert it?

As suggested, I tried:

```
print(''.join(["{0:x}".format(ord(char)) for char in dl_dst[2:-1]]))
```

But the printed resuls is `275c5c7861302d5c5c7866635c5c7861335c5c7866385c5c78643927`, which is **not** what I expected.

Comment: That does not appear to be a valid byte string, where did you get it?

Comment: How did this string: `a = "b'\xa0-\xfc\xa3\xf8\xd9'" ` come about? It *looks* like someone had a bytes object, then wrote the *string representation of a bytes object* to a file. You should fix that. You *cannot decode a string*, you can *encode* a string to bytes, and *decode bytes* to strings. You could use `eval` here to get the bytes represented by that string

Comment: Please add the line that breaks my solution as well.

Comment: Done. Your solution does not break, but does not give the correct answer (ONLY when I read the value from the file).

Answer (score 3):

This should get you the result you want assuming `a` is a escaped `str`.

```
a = "b'\xa0-\xfc\xa3\xf8\xd9'"
res = ["{0:x}".format(ord(char)) for char in a[2:-1]]
res = ''.join(res)
print(res) # a02dfca3f8d9
```

**Note:**
`a[2:-1]` removes the `b'` and `'` from the input `str`.
`ord()` returns the integer of a unicode character.
`{0:x}` returns a `str` hex representation of a given `int`.
`''.join` turns the entire list into one `str`.

That can be onelined but for convenience and readability I left it as two.

Note you should probably fix your source so it does not output that way (it should not output `b'...'` to a file).

---

**- EDIT -**

Since you have a raw `str` it needs to be done differently. Instead of doing split to get the MAC address from your `fm_line` just use regex (less hassle), also your file is reading in raw strings meaning `\` becomes escaped so you need to fix that. This solution will work for raw or escaped strings.

```
import re
import ast
get_mac = re.compile(r"dl_dst=b'(.+?)',") # This should be outside of your loop.
result = get_mac.search(fm_line) # This you will call for each line that you need to parse
if result:
    address = ast.literal_eval(f"'{result.group(1)}'") # This will turn your raw `str` in an escaped `str`
    res = ["{0:x}".format(ord(char)) for char in address]
    res = ''.join(res)
    print(res)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works if I define 'a' in the code. But if I read 'a' from the file, the output is 5c7861302d5c7866635c7861335c7866385c786439, which is not correct! In debugging mode, the value of 'a' is 'b\\'\\xa0-\\xfc\\xa3\\xf8\\xd9\\''.

Comment: An OpenFlow switch is creating this file, this value is supposed to be a Mac Address (a0:2d:fc:a3:f8:d9). Can you make a test file with this value and try to read it? It looks weird for me why your script does not work!

Comment: I added a part of the file in the question.

Comment: @AmirVarasteh please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks for your edit! The output is still incorrect "5c7861302d5c7866635c7861335c7866385c786439"

Comment: @AmirVarasteh what does it output? I don't get that output with normal str or raw string.

Comment: I also get the right output reading from a file. Did you try my old edit or the new one?

Comment: Hi. Thanks!! I just saw your new edit. It works now!